# How to find the repository of a GitHub pages behind an A record

Tags: dns, github-pages

I had a bug in my DNS config - because I used to host my websites on-premise, I had a wildcard A record pointing to an IP address. The problem is that I recently moved to GitHub pages et voilá: someone took over a subdomain of my domain and made it point to it's GitHub repo, ultimately pointing to some scam page.

The question now is: How to find the repository that contains the CNAME file containing my subdomain?

`dig` won't work because it's an A record. I already parsed the "scam page" for additional hints without success. I tried searching GitHub without success. I assume it's behind a non-public repository now. So I wonder: How to find the source?

(of course, I already removed the wildcard record)